# Capturing Session/Request Data in the Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, models

I am developing system event tracking feature that logs events such as login, logout, unauthorized access, wrong password, published content, etc. I wish to capture request data, such as remote_ip, session id, request type, etc.

I understand that ideally, you should not access request data in the model, and rather pass it in the controller, something like this:

articles#edit:

```
@article.update_attributes(params[:article])
Event.create(:eventable => @article, :request => request)
```

Often, however, Events will be created in rake tasks or even console, so I want to take this code out of the controller and into the models, something like this:

```
class Article
  after_save :create_event

  def create_event
    Event.create(:message => "aritcle_updated")
  end
end
```

Then in the Event class:

```
class Event
   before_create :record_ip_address

   def record_ip_address
     # This is how I want it, I don't know how to access request here!
     self.ip = request.remote_ip # How to access request?
   end
end
```

What's the best way to accomplish that, and how to access Request object in the Model?

*Note, the Event model does NOT require the request to be present - I just want it to process it if it's available*

Comment: Callbacks are a good way to go about this. ideally you can do a callback and assign the event object with attributes and save that with the help of the self.attribute to assign it if it has relationship in the model you are capturing on.

Comment: Yeah, the question is how to access the request data in the model?

Comment: I am confused. So which is your request data here in the example you mentioned above.? Another idea would be to save the data and do an update attributes in the model in after_save callback, although this does violate the MVC architecture itself.

Comment: I understand now as to what you are trying to do. Ideal way would be to have a request table and use that table as a foreign key for your Events table. Once you use that as a Foreign key u can figure out the ip using self.request.remote_ip